# Different alignment in same line

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

SX. I want frame number to have right alignment and frame title left alignment. And command `\hfill` does not help me with it.
`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title \hfill\hfill\insertframenumber}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`

[image: The result is next]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also `filll`, stronger than `fill` from `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{Title \hfill\hfill\insertframenumber}
\frametitle{Title \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}\insertframenumber}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Can you provide this solution as command, e.g. \customtitle[Title text]? That would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `\hskip` to where you want it to go:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title\hskip4.3in\insertframenumber}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontenc}  

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title\hskip\textwidth\insertframenumber}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]